# Unable to find text although it is present

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

I am learning web-scraping with Python. I wrote code to retrieve company names form one of Indian yellow pages

```
r =  requests.get("http://xyzxyz", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "col-sm-5"}):
    coLink = link.find("span" , {"class" : "jcn"})
    companyName = coLink.find("a").text
```

I am getting error  " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'". I know we get this error if object does not find anything. However if when I print(coLink), It gives following link inside every span class

```
<span class="jcn"><a href="http://xyz/Kolkata/Sunrise-International-&lt;near&gt;-B-R-B-Basu-Road-/033P3001041_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUYXBlciBSb2xsZXIgQmVhcmluZyBEZWFsZXJz" onclick="_ct('clntnm', 'lspg');" title="Sunrise International in , Kolkata">Sunrise International</a>
</span>
<span class="jcn"><a href="http://xyz/Kolkata/Shree-Shakti-Vyapaar-PVT-LTD/033P6001995_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUYXBlciBSb2xsZXIgQmVhcmluZyBEZWFsZXJz" onclick="_ct('clntnm', 'lspg');" title="Shree Shakti Vyapaar PVT LTD in , Kolkata">Shree Shakti Vyapaar PVT LTD</a>
</span>
```

Can you please help how to get text of company?

Comment: Are you sure that all `span.jcn` tags have inside an `a` tag?

Comment: so adding simple exception will solve this issue by ignoring all span.jcn those does not have a tag inside?

Comment: In any case, you should check first, if the `coLink.find("a")` returns a tag that you can get the text or it returns `None`.

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas As I mentioned in my question, I already tried print(colink). I also provided output of that print. and you can see in output that "a" is there.

Comment: I was not suggest to print but to check what the `find` function returns and if returns a `None`, not try to get the text because you will cause an exception.

Comment: Perfect, got your point. I created an exception, which will pass such records. and it is working fine now.

Comment: Nice! remember to upvote comments! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not explaining the current problem, but providing an alternative solution - you can use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match the desired `a` elements:

```
for link in soup.select(".col-sm-5 .jcn a"):
    print(link.get_text())
```

This way you would not get any errors in case there is a `span` with no `a` link inside.

Note that `col-sm-5` is a terrible class name to be using to locate elements - it is UI/layout-specific and has a high chance of being changed.

Comment: After correcting small syntax in your code  :                                            r =  requests.get("http://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Taper-Roller-Bearing-Dealers", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

for link in soup.select({".col-sm-5 .jcn a"}):
 print(link.get_text())                                                                                                  now it gives "'set' object has no attribute 'read'".

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara yup, fixed the typo. But this error you are getting could not be related to the presented code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\pyt\justdial.py", line 15, in <module>
    for link in soup.select({".col-sm-5 .jcn a"}):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1349, in select
    tokens = shlex.split(selector)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shlex.py", line 273, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shlex.py", line 263, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File

Comment: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shlex.py", line 90, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shlex.py", line 118, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'read' ........It is showing for loop only.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara ah, sure, you've fixed the typo incorrectly, remove the curly braces. Sorry for the typo again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Today is teacher's day in India. Thanks being my Python teacher :)

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara and this is a "Labor day" in the States. Thanks for putting labor into trying to fix my buggy code :) Feel free to accept the answer if it deserves. Thanks!